# Detecting when right mouse button was clicked only

Tags: java, jtable

My table has 4 columns, and I only want column 1 to be allowed to be clicked. Also, this code also allows the LEFT mouse button to be used, I only want the RIGHT button.

```
    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int iCol = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();

    if(iCol == 1 && evt.getModifiers() == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)
    {
        if(evt.getClickCount() == 2)
        {
            int iRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

            File iFile = new File(jTable1.getValueAt(iRow, iCol).toString());

            String iPath = iFile.getAbsolutePath();
            File iDir = new File(iPath.substring(0, iPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator)));

            if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(iDir);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this question turned out as 2.

Comment: Isn't the left button normally `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK`?

Comment: Why? You already check for `iCol == 1`. Anyway. You can control selection in specific rows, via [setSelectionModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionModel(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel)), but I don't know how to control the columns.

Comment: @ignis I think the OP is more interested in only reacting to a double click on column 1 more then restricting the selection.  But you should be able to use the `ColumnModel`'s selection model to do control the column selection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the clicking only of a specific column:

1. create the table using you own model.

```
final JTable table = new JTable( new MyTableModel(data, columnNames));
```

2. create the new model overriding the function you need (i.e. isCellEditable)

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8422360723278074044L;

    MyTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames )    
    {
      super(data,columnNames);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int cols)
     {
       if(cols==1 ){return true;}
          return false;                                                                                    
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm uber new in java, I'm not sure where to place `final JTable table = new JTable( new MyTableModel(data, columnNames));`. Wouldn't that create a new table? I already created one in the editor. Here's how I set the model: `DefaultTableModel model;

        Object columnNames[] = { "Name", "Path", "Last Modified", "Size" };
        model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        jTable1.setModel(model);`  Replacing `DefaultTableModel` to `MyTableModel` gives an error.

Comment: Changing it to `MyTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int data )    
        {
          super(columnNames, data);
        }` seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with, left button is normally represented by `MouseEvent.BUTTON1`, then move onto `MouseEvent#getModifiers` is usually used to provide information about what keys are currently pressed and we begin to see the major problems.

The method you really want is `MouseEvent#getButton`

Try run the following example for some ideas ;)

```
public class TestMouseClicked {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMouseClicked();
    }

    public TestMouseClicked() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new MousePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MousePane extends JPanel {

        private JToggleButton leftButton;
        private JToggleButton middleButton;
        private JToggleButton rightButton;

        public MousePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            leftButton = new JToggleButton("Left");
            middleButton = new JToggleButton("Middle");
            rightButton = new JToggleButton("Right");

            add(leftButton);
            add(middleButton);
            add(rightButton);

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(leftButton);
            bg.add(middleButton);
            bg.add(rightButton);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getButton());
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        leftButton.setSelected(true);
                    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
                        middleButton.setSelected(true);
                    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                        rightButton.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```